# QGIS - How to split and display Population Data according to District/Province?

Tags: qgis, overlay, extract, population, flood

I'm a complete beginner in QGIS, currently self-teaching myself through Youtube.

Current Problem: To split and display population data according to district/province

Project Background: To measure extent of floods in the various district/province and estimate the population affected there.

I've also been playing around with zonal statistics, but am unsure if its of any use to the above.

Files I currently have:

1. Population raster data (from WorldPop.org)
2. District.shp & Province.shp (both MultiPolygon)
3. GADM .shp files
4. Eed.shp (flood exposure map in grid cells)
5. Tif and tif.ovr (of the province in a certain year)

Comment: I suggest you break down your workflow into smaller steps, which you can research individually. You also should have a look at the official QGIS tutorial.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is your specific goal?

Comment: Edit: Added current problem and project background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Zonal statistics](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgiszonalstatisticsfb) with pop. raster as input raster and Districts as input layer. Statistics to calculate = Sum

> Calculates statistics of a raster layer for each feature of an
> overlapping polygon vector layer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `shp` with two polygons (*p1* and *p2*) and your `raster` layer (*worldpop*). In order to clip your raster based on your polygons (i.e., create two raster layers, *worldpop_p1* and *worldpop_p2*), what you need to do is:

1. select the p1 using the `Select features by area` tool

[image: select features by area]

2. Use `SAGA`'s tool `Clip raster with polygon` (you can find it in the `Processing toolbox`)

[image: clip raster]

3. Repeat the process for the rest of your polygons

Comment: Is the output file supposed to be a raster? How do I display the numerical values obtained from it?
And yes, I do have 2 MultiPolygon shp files (District and Province respectively)

Comment: The output(s) will be two raster layers. Each raster will have the shape of the shp you used to clip your worlpop raster.